# Double Click event is not working on ListBox using MVVM in WPF app

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am facing a problem while binding the double click event on Listbox item.
I am using MVVM and Prism. I didn't understand what is wrong here.

View

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Cities , Source={StaticResource vmC}}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCity , Source={StaticResource vmC}}" Width="100" Height="200">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                        <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick"                                           
                                  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.ItemSelectedCommand}"/>
                        </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

ViewModel

```
public class CityViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
       
        public DelegateCommand ItemSelectedCommand { get; private set; }

        public string SelectedCity { get; set; }

        public List<string> Cities { get; private set; }

        public CityViewModel()
        {
            ItemSelectedCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnItemSelected);
            Cities = new List<string>() { "Bangalore", "New York", "Sydney", "London", "Washington" };
        }

        private void OnItemSelected()
        {
            var city = SelectedCity;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`MouseBinding` is not part of the visual tree. This means, you cannot use `Binding.RelativeSource` as there is no tree to traverse.
Instead you must bind to the current `DataContext`, which is the item's data model. To accomplish this, you would have tzo introduce a model class e.g. `City` that exposes a `Name` and `ItemSelectedCommand` property.

If moving the command to the item model doesn't make sense in your scenario, you should use a `RoutedCommand` and handle it e.g., in the parent `Window`. `InputBinding` is primarily intended to be used in the view only and therefore encourages the use of `RoutedCommand`.

In your case, it seems you are only interested in notifying the `CityViewModel` that the selection has changed. In this case simply call `OnItemSelected` from the `SelectedCity` property `set()`:

```cs
public class CityViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  private string selectedCity;
  public string SelectedCity
  {
    get => selectedCity;
    set
    {
      selectedCity = value;
      OnItemSelected();
    }
  }

  public List<string> Cities { get; private set; }

  public CityViewModel()
  {
    ...
  }

  private void OnItemSelected()
  {
    var city = SelectedCity;
  }
}
```

Comment: No I want it to on double click that's what i Write in the question, Only doubleclick event is needed.

Comment: Yes, and I wrote that you can't bind to the command using RelativeSource. And that you would have to move the command to the actual item model i.e. the DataContext of the DataTemplate, or use a RoutedCommand. You can also handle the event in the code-behind.